# error in quantmod package in getSymbols function

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm using `quantmod` package

I want to execute the following code:

```
 getSymbols('YHOO')
```

I have always this warning message.

Warning message:

> In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
>     downloaded length 141628 != reported length 200

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It does not matter if you add the data to to the Global Environment or another new environment. Which versions of R, quantmod are you using?

Comment: warnings and errors are not the same thing. Please be clear on which you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error can be solved with this code, which is directly from the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf) of the package:

```
data.env <- new.env()
getSymbols("YHOO", env=data.env)
```

You have to create a new environment. I hope this will solve your problems.

Comment: SAME WARNING MESSAGE !